# Does adding outputs from processing tools in a list save them as layers?

Tags: pyqgis

```
import processing

layers = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()

supply=[]
sub="supply"
for layer in layers:
    if sub in layer.name():  
supply.append(processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer",layer,55,10,False,None))

demand=[]
substring="demand"
for layer in layers:
    if substring in layer.name():
        demand.append(processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer",layer,55,10,False,None))

finalints=[]

for s in supply:
    for d in demand:
        intersections_1=[]
        intersections_1.append((processing.runalg("qgis:intersection",s,d,None)))
    finalints.append((intersections_1))
    del(intersections_1)
print(finalints)
```

Does this save the obtained output files as layers in the list? If so, how can I add the layers saved in the list onto my map? Also, am not able to get intersections of the layers stored in such lists with output as "Unable to run algorithm".

Answer (score 0):

You have intersection alg in double brackets, maybe thats the reason. Is there more output when you run it other than "Unable to run algorithm"?

To load layers:

```
for layer in finalints:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```